# What is the best raiding strategy to get gold at townhall level 5?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am at level 5 Townhall, and I want to upgrade my walls.

I'm not good at raiding. Which would be the best troops to train to get gold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All builds are different but in my opinion you should not be working on your walls at all at this time.  If you face any enemy that is strong enough to blow past your defenses (cannons, archer towers, etc), they will get past your walls.

## TIPS at Townhall Level 5

At this TH level, You should try and focus on **farming & building.**  I do not recommend going for trophies or otherwise known as *cupping*.  The more trophies you have, [99% of the time] the harder the opponent you are trying to farm from.

Try to max out your camps, barracks, and Clan Castle (which you also have to be in a clan) first so you can have the max number of troops to attack / farm with.  At TH level 5, these are the max building levels:

[image]

**At townhall level 5, max level barracks is level 7, max level Army Camp is 5 and max level Clan Castle is 2.**

[image]

Note the unlocked units at Barracks level 7.  The strongest unit you have is the Wizard, although you should factor in cost of elixir per attack.

[image]

As the picture above shows, you can have a max of 3 level 5 army camps which will hold a total of **135 troops**.   Take the **135 troops + 15 troops** from a full clan Castle (which again you must request from clan members) = **150 Total** attacking troops.

The last factor you have to put into perspective is what league you are in.  My recommendation from average opponent strength would be these builds:

**TL;DR**

### Trophies 0-1400

- 10 Giants (housing space of 5 each) = 50
- 50 Barbarians (housing space of 1 each) = 50
- 8 Wall breakers (housing space of 2 each) = 16
- 29 Archers (housing space of 1 each) = 29  **OR** 29 Goblins (housing space of 1 each)

Total of 150

If elixir and time is not a factor when farming, then a good tank & heavy DPS build should do the trick.

- 15 Giants = 75
- 10 Wall breakers = 20
- 12 Wizards (housing space of 4) = 48
- 2 Goblins/barbarians/archers = 2

Total of 150

Have your Giants be your tanks.  They will go for defenses first.  While the defenses are distracted by your tanks, try to attack their resources.

As I mentioned above, I do not recommend going for trophies.  Once you have the majority of your opponents resources, quit the attack by tapping the Surrender button.

The more gold you have, the more you should focus on protecting your resources for when you are not playing.  Therefore, I would advise putting your gold back into upgrading your defenses such as cannons, archer towers, etc.   Try not to upgrade your walls past level 5 as you should put those resources elsewhere.

Comment: I recently got all my walls to level 5

Answer (score 3):

If you have level 7 barracks I would recommend using a archer/barbarian/goblin strategy with wizards to finish. Because your wizards may be lower level, I would suggest using only 3-5 of them. Another good thing is to use 4 giants as distraction from the mortars and using smaller troops to destroy everything else.

Answer (score 1):

TH6 and now TH8 and all been using 12 giants, 6 wall breakers, 1 healer, 40 goblins and the rest archers. I have gotten so much loot that i run out of storage. especially elixir storage. this combo should yeild around 100k+ of gold and 100k+ of exilir. I have taken 400k of each and did not completely destroy their base. Again we are farming not pushing trophies. :)

Comment: How are you still using healers? I ruled them out once I got to near end lvl 7 townhall. They die too quickly and healing potions don't worry about air defense.

Comment: @BakedPotato First you have to take AD if all AD is distributed. If All AD are centralized don't use healer. You are attacking a base from one side only so from that side if any AD is there means take it out quickly and deploy healer.

Answer (score 0):

TH5 - raiding with this method: 1 lightning spell, any 15 donated troops, 3 wall breakers,4 or 5 giants, 2 ballons, 2 or 3 wizards, 15 archers and the rest of them barbarians. You must have 3 upgraded army camps and 120 space. Your clan castle must be at level 2.

First, drop a lightning spell on mortar, drop 3 wall breakers near the wall close to the gold storage. Place your giants, and after that all of your barbarians and donated troops at the same time. Drop your archers anywhere you want - I suggest you drop them at elixir storages or gold mines. After that, you must drop your wizards and balloons. You surround the map with this. At the end you will win 1 or 2 stars and have stolen 80 percent of resources from your opponent. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

BALLOOONS BALLOOONS BALLOOONS :D I use 30 level 2 balloons for a camp space of 120. I totally destroy every land i pass by. But I don't attack those with a very high level of archer towers or those having their air defense in the middle or have two upgraded air defenses. Try to aim for those having their air defenses on the out side which makes it easier for balloons to destroy them at first.

Answer (score 0):

Use

- 4/6 giants
- 3 wall breakers
- 60/80 goblins
- 20/30 barbarians
- 10/20 archers

Answer (score 0):

Always get at least 6 giants, and tap them near the main defenses like wizard tower mortars because they are the strongest.

While they are attacking and distracting, then tap the goblins (the quickest and strongest at breaking) near the gold or elixir storage and take all the resources.

Go for trophies because you get bonuses when you're in a league.  For example, I'm in the master league, so I get 50,000 gold and elixir.